# Trying to load jquery into tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I am writing a script which logs into my college network when the login page is loaded.

The code looks as follows

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      <College login page>
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==    
$(document).ready(function() {

    var usr=document.getElementsByName("username");

    var pass = document.getElementByName("password");

    usr.value="usrname";    
    pass.value="password";    

    var submitButton = document.querySelector ('input[type="submit"][value="Login"]');

    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');

    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);

    submitButton.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);

    });
```

The console shows a error saying

```
$ is not defined
```

Can someone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 367, accepted):

You need to have a `@require` in the user script header to load jQuery. Something like:

```
// @require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
```

(Selecting your desired version from the of [list of available versions of jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery/))

Comment: Please don't use `jquery-latest`.
https://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/

Comment: Be warned that this may interfere with the page's own definition of `$`

Comment: @Owen and how would we deal with that

Comment: @Menasheh [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

Comment: Also be aware the the page's own jQuery may come along and clobber the `@require`d version. `noConflict` will also help with that.

Comment: To deal with 2 jQeries clashing, jQery provides a relinquishing mechanism.More info [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

Answer (score 14):

For future googlers,

If you have used the above method and still jQuery doesn't seem to be loaded by your script try looking at the spaces, And try to match the indentation with the rest of the header. Apparently the indentation is important.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js 
              ^ here should be correct amount of spaces
...
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Just a thought: can't the accepted answer be edited instead of an extra post ?

Comment: By that logic, every answer would end up with just one very long answer edited over time. Don't you think?

Comment: to be honest, a comment like "take care of indent when inserting @require" would also be enough and could easily be edited. and i agree a bit with your statement in the comment above, but on the other hand, if every question had several answeres, than the answere isnt good enough. even one LONG answere is may just bad explained ^^